# Why responsive web design respond differently on screens that have the same resolution but different ppi?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

When using media queries you can set the min-width property and design accordingly but I'm testing using both my desktop and my mobile phone. My phone resolution is 1080p, the same as my desktop monitor however the design respond differently on both screens. It should behave the same shouldn't it? What am I missing? Why do they behave differently if I'm only using pixels?

Comment: Are you using the same viewport meta tags?

Comment: I'm not using any actually :\

Comment: You should try using <meta name="viewport" content="width=1080, initial-scale=1">

Comment: No, that's most definitely NOT a good idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out a **CSS pixel** is different from a **hardware pixel**.

CSS specification says:

> If the pixel density of the output device is very different from that
>   of a typical computer display, the user agent should rescale pixel
>   values. It is recommended that the pixel unit refer to the whole
>   number of device pixels that best approximates the reference pixel. It
>   is recommended that the reference pixel be the visual angle of one
>   pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from
>   the reader of an arm's length.

This is a good read:
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Answer (score 0):

Just got stung by this. The following line of code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

in the `<head>` tags solved it perfectly for me.